# str object has no attribute get in tkinter

Tags: python, python-requests

I have done the following script I have error in the this line

```
available_attributes.extend([attribute.get('name') for attribute in
response])
```

I try some changes to change the string, but I can't fix it by the way.

Script:

```
import requests
import json

def process_attributes(attributes: list) -> dict:
   available_attributes = []
   endpoint = 'https://{}/wp-json/wc/v3/products/attributes'.format(host)
   response = requests.get(endpoint, auth=auth)
   print(response.status_code)
   response = response.json()

   available_attributes.extend([attribute.get('name') for attribute in response])
   unavailable_attributes = list(set(attributes) - set(available_attributes))
   if len(unavailable_attributes) != 0:
   start = 0
   end = 100
   while True:
        if end >= len(unavailable_attributes):
            end = len(unavailable_attributes)
```

Comment: `response` is apparently a list of strings, not a list of dictionaries. Use `print(response)` to see it.

Comment: What does Tkinter have to do with this? You're just processing the response from an API call.

Comment: actually is just 1 part of the whole code i upload for the specific error line, and i am updating products on live website using this script

Comment: What you're doing with it is irrelevant to the question at hand.

Comment: i am updating the some products on live website , it was working fine but now i get this error,

Comment: The error is because at least one of the `attribute`s is a string, not a dictionary.

Comment: so how i can resolve this??

Comment: Show the value of `response`

Comment: this is i am getting after the error<Response [401]>

Comment: File "/home/arslan/Documents/personel/scrature/Paul-WooCommerce/update_stocks-1.py", line 18, in <listcomp>
    available_attributes.extend([attribute.get('name') for attribute in response])
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
<Response [401]>

Comment: I know that's the error you're getting, you put it in the question.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.

Comment: Do you understand what the error means?

Comment: let me send you whole code you will get the point

Comment: this is the link for the whole script you can test it by the way :https://gofile.io/d/MHbuNi

Comment: We don't want to see your whole code (esp an off-site link to it). What's needed it the shortest code possible that will reproduce the problem. Without that, we can only make guesses…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently your `response` list contains some strings mixed in with the dictionaries. You can check the type of `attribute` and skip it if it's not a `dict`.

```
available_attributes.extend([attribute.get('name') for attribute in response if isinstance(attribute, dict)])
```

Comment: `.get()` is also a method that tkinter Variables have (see [The Variable Classes (BooleanVar, DoubleVar, IntVar, StringVar)](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm)).

Comment: can you please download the whole script in the mentioned link bellow to test it thoroughly it would be a great help        https://gofile.io/d/MHbuNi

Comment: @martineau But you can't get a Tkinter variable from JSON.

Comment: @Arslanminko I asked you to put the value of `response` in the question. Without details like that I'm just guess. I'm not going to download your whole application.

Comment: okay sir i did this but its not fixed the error actually so thats why i sent a file

Comment: Where did you do it? I don't see it in the question.